# $T$ is well defined and $T^{-1}$ is not continuous.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $E=C([0,1], \mathbb{R})$ with norm $\sup$ and $T: E \to E$ with $f \in E$ :

$$Tf: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$$ 
$$t \mapsto \int_0^t f(s) ds$$

Prove that $T$ is well defined that means $Tf$ is continuous and $T^{-1}$ is not continuous ?

The problem is finding $\left \| T \right \|$ and i have done but firstly i can't show this operator is well defined

Comment: If I well understand: $Tf=F$ is a primitve of $f$ and $f$ is continuous, so $F$ is derivable with continuous derivative.

Answer (score 1):

The operator is well defined if, for every $f\in E$,

1. You can calculate $Tf$.
2. $Tf$ is also in $E$.

In other words, for your particular problem, you have to show that if $f$ is a continuous function, then $Tf$ exists and is a continuous function.

---

To show that $T^{-1}$ is not continuous, you need to first tell us what metric or norm you are using on $E$.

Comment: Thank you @5xum but why $Tf \in E$? and norm is sup norm

Comment: ohh ok it's well defined

Comment: @NguyễnĐăngKhảiHoàn Well, by definition, when is any function in $E$? For example, is $f(x)=x^2$ in $E$?

Comment: ohhh sorry but i don't understand your question? i have already understood $T$ is well defined. Can you explain your question